# How should I configure development-testing environment for a SIP gateway

Tags: c#, .net, voip, sip

I have to do an integration point between an .net application and SIP (iptel.org) provider. All seems simple but I feel like I don't have much control if I use an external server like iptel.org.

> The use case is: As an consumer I
>   should be able to do a call with the
>   Phone Number and the Short Message and
>   treat/report execution status.

For this reason I want to set up my development environment in a way that i can write/test/log the integration interaction.

Here is what I inted to do:

> **SIP server**   : miniSipServer ... which will keep my acounts 
>   **Soft
>   phone** : Express Talk ... for making
>   sure the server is running and ready
>   to work
>   **SIP stack for .net**  : SipekSDK with pjsipDll

Resources:
http://sites.google.com/site/sipekvoip/ 
http://sipsorcery.codeplex.com/ 
http://callbutler.codeplex.com/

the enumerated resources have not trivial code which is a learning curve for a beginr

Your advice of

> - where to look for samples
> - how to wrap it up in less intrusive way
> - which are the best tools to be configured in dev/testing environment

will be greatly apreciated

Thanks,
Ruslan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the sipsorcery author so I can give you some information on it. The project includes a [SIP Proxy](http://sipsorcery.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/60273#299694) which is easy to get up and running. Writing the IronPython script to control how the proxy routes traffic is not so straight forward however if all you are doing is forwarding SIP traffic between your app and iptel it's a lot simpler.

The project is fairly active and there's a dedicated [forum](http://forum.sipsorcery.com/viewforum.php?f=3&sid=ab7e6be1b938c37fdac072dca69815e4) for developers to get help on.